# Passing TObjectList as Parameter - Delphi Xe2

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I have a "Form 1" which sends a list of objects to "Form 2" through parameter. But Delphi send the list as a reference, so if I close release the list of "Form 1" error occurs in "Form 2"

As Sample:

Form1:

```
var list: TObjectList<TPerson>;
    begin

      list  :=  TObjectList<TPerson>.Create();

      Try

      list.Add(TPerson.Create('JOHN', 29));
      list.Add(TPerson.Create('MARK', 27));

      Form2.getList(list);


      Finally
       FreeAndNil(list);
      End;
```

Problem is that after releasing the list in the "Form 1" reference points to an object that has been released.

The question is:

How to send a list to the "form 2" as a copy and not a reference?

Thanks!

Comment: Harder than you might think. Step 1 is to convert TPerson into a value type, that is a record. Once you've done that list copying becomes a one-liner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the exact way the question was formulated, the answer is "not possible", since **TObjectList<T>** is a class and classes in Delphi are reference types.

In fact, what you pass to the method **Form2.getList()** is a value, but that value is a reference, so it works very  like passing the value by reference.

If you need to have a copy of the list, you have to do it yourself, however, the variable **list** has a reference to a list that **owns** the items, so even if you create a second list inside **Form2** and simply add those items existing in the list received as parameter, the items will continue to be destroyed when the list is destroyed in **Form1**.

In your place I would implement my **Form2.getList** the move the items from the list in **Form1** to the list in **Form2**. Something like this:

```
procedure TForm2.getList(aPeople: TObjectList<TPerson>);
begin
  while aPeople.Count>0 do
    FPeople.Add(aPeople.Extract(aPeople[0]));
end;
```

In this code **FPeople** is a data member of **TForm2** declared as **TObjectList<TPerson>**. The **Extract** method removes an item from the list without freeing it. So, after being extracted, the item will be added to the internal list. Because it´s not in the external list anymore it won´t be freed when the list is.

Comment: Exactly, you perfectly understood my placements. I had already written the code like yours and it works! But I wonder if it would be possible to create a copy of the list without loop all items. I believe not.

Answer (score 1):

Form2 would need to either take ownership of the list and not let Form1 free it, or else loop through the list copying the contents to its own local list.

Comment: I would think moving the variable above the scope of Form1 could be another option.

Answer (score 0):

Check ownership of the `Tobjectlist`, if you free the list and the list owns the objects, it will free the objects in the list when the list is freed.

Try `TObjectList<TPerson>.Create(false)`;